# How to send result in survey monkey using CURL

Tags: api, curl, surveymonkey

I create a new survey form using survey monkey, and i get all questions using api and create custom form in my site. Now how can we update the result in survey monkey using CURL. I tired this `/surveys/{id}/pages/{id}/questions/{id}` but no response.

Version : V3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By "update the result" I presume you mean you want to create a new response for your survey.

You can do that with the [response API](https://developer.surveymonkey.com/api/v3/#collectors-id-responses). There is cURL examples on the right side of the page. Something along the lines of:

```
curl -i -X POST https://api.surveymonkey.net/v3/collectors/{collector_id}/responses \
     -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Authorization:bearer <your_access_token>" \
     -d '{
            "pages": [{
                "id": "<page_id>",
                "questions": [{
                    "answers": [{
                        "choice_id": "<choice_id>"
                    }],
                    "id": "<question_id>"
                }, {
                    "answers": [{
                        "text": "<open ended response>"
                    }],
                    "id": "<question_id>"
                }]
            }]
         }'
```

Depending on the question types you have in your survey. Make sure you have a collector created already.

Given you are just trying to embed a survey on your website, I recommend you just use a [website collector](https://help.surveymonkey.com/articles/en_US/kb/Website-Collector) instead of trying to automate this yourself (depending on your use case).

Comment: Thank you for your time.

Comment: I got this error. "Invalid schema in the body provided". And which collect did i need to use.

Comment: This is my json : {"pages":[{"id":"25235","questions":[{"answers":[{"text":"example"}],"id":1213},{"answers":
[{"text":"example@gmail.com"}],"id":1231},{"answers":[{"choice_id":"Male"}],"id":1235
},{"answers":[{"text":"test test"}],"id":1236}]}]}

Comment: @RajMohan the ID for the questions need to all be strings. `"1236"`

Comment: Just changed value of ID for post here.

Comment: Depends on what you're trying to do, the usual is `weblink`

Comment: Got thanks, the issue is question id i sent as integer, but api accept only string,